# How to pass a parameter to new/init in AASM gem

Tags: ruby, aasm

I'm trying to make a finite state machine chain with AASM gem. I want to check if a string is unique (not existing in the database).

I wrote:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aasm'

class Term
  include AASM

  aasm do
    state :Beginning, :initial => true
    state :CheckUniqueness

    def initialize(term)
        print term
    end

    event :UniquenessChecking do
        print "Check uniqueness"
      transitions :from => :Beginning, :to => :CheckUniqueness
    end

  end

end

term = Term.new("textstring")
term.CheckUniqueness
```

But when I use `Term.new("textstring")`, it doesn't allow me to pass a parameter I think, because I get a error:

```
`initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
 from try.rb:24:in `new'
 from try.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

Is it possible to pass a parameter with init in AASM? I would like to know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `initialize` inside of the `aasm` block, just move it out of that block:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aasm'

class Term
  include AASM

  def initialize(term)
    print term
  end

  aasm do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks works, is it also possible to acces `term` value in `aasm do`? I tried `self.term`.

Comment: I think `initialize` is now runned as last, because I first get printed lines by puts from the AASM events and then the print from `initialize`. How can I use `term` in the events?

Comment: Sorry, I was able to help you with your invalid nesting, but I am don't have deep knowledge in the internals of AASM. I suggest to ask another question if you have other issues with your code that aren't related to this question.